# How do I decorate a client method to wrap authentication in Azure Mobile App Services?

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, custom-attributes, azure-mobile-services

The system in question is a Mobile App Services Xamarin.Forms app with a C# 5.0 / MVC 5.0 / Web API 2.0 backend. The app uses LoginAsync for custom authentication on the client and "[Authorize]" decorations on ApiController and TableController classes and methods on the backend.  Currently there is no *automatic* workflow to display custom authentication screens when an Unauthorized HTTP Status Code is returned for backend calls. It is repetitive and bulky to add the, below, authentication code on the client for *every* method that makes a database call.  I'd like to create a custom client-side attribute (or equivalent) which can be used to decorate client classes or methods that will handle authentication if an Unauthorized response is given.

The wrapped method should functionally go inside this construct:

`try
{
    ... // Decorated, attributed, or wrapped method
} 
catch(MobileServiceInvalidOperationException msioe) 
{
    if(msioe.Response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) {
        ... // Perform login activities
    }
}`

How do I achieve a simple way to apply the same authentication code to selected methods (e.g. using a custom attribute derived from IActionFilterAttribute or IAuthenticationFilter)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to add a delegating handler that catches the 401 response and starts the authentication flow. Here's an example of how to do this: https://github.com/azure-appservice-samples/ContosoMoments/blob/dev/src/Mobile/ContosoMoments/AuthHandler.cs.

To use, add it as a parameter to your `MobileServiceClient` constructor call:

`new MobileServiceClient(URL, new AuthHandler());`